# Why does this not send an image in discord?

Tags: python, api, discord, bots

I have my python discord bot set up so it should send a pizza image when someone types $pizza.
this is the code to send the image. MYACCESSKEY is filled in with my api key from the unsplash api website.

```
response = requests.get("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=<MYACCESSKEY>")
links = response.json()['urls']
print(links)
link = links['regular']
print(link)
await message.channel.send(requests.get(link))
```

'<Response [200]>' is what my bot sends in the discord server. When I click on the link that the link variable outputs I get an image in my browser. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you just do `await message.channel.send(link)`? Discord should automatically display the image.

Comment: Shouldn't you send `link` instead of the response object ?

Comment: Thanks to both of you! This worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`link` is the link to an image, so just do `await message.channel.send(link)`.